# How to translate the physical unit "ccm" into English

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate an old (1972) German scientific paper and there's a unit for measuring bacteria concentrations in water that I can't work out the English equivalent of. "ccm", with values between 180-8000 in this paper (measured near graves in a groundwater-logged cemetery, for what it's worth).

I wondered if it might be equivalent to cfu/mL (colony forming units) or a related unit, but this seems to be translated as KBE (Koloniebildende Einheit). Have also checked the usual sources (LEO, google, wikipedia etc) and have had no luck. If anyone's able to help, I'd be very grateful!

[image: Screenshot from paper:]

Comment: ccm = cubic centimeter

Comment: Haha, I can't believe it's that obvious. But would a German say that or "kcm".

Assuming it is ccm, then it presumably is equivalent to cfu/mL (1 cm3 = 1 mL). Can anyone confirm?

Comment: They like to use English or Latinic abbreviations, too.

Comment: @TimM Do you have a link to that paper? I can confirm peterh is right. Especially in science, words and  abbreviation with Latin or Greek origin are common.

Comment: This seems to be a typewriter-written document - In contemporary writing with a computer, this would most probably simply be *cm²*

Comment: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/ccm) would have provided the answer easily.

Comment: @tofro That's square centimetres; it should be _cm^3_

Comment: Thanks everyone. After your answers and talking to a microbiologist colleague I'm pretty confident it is cfu/mL.

@Marzipanherz - I don't have a link, but can email you a pdf if you need more info on cemetery discharges to groundwater in your life!

Comment: Actually, found it online here: https://www.dbges.de/de/system/files/mitteilungen_dbg/Mitteilungen%20der%20DBG%201972_16.pdf

(pages 225-229)

Comment: @TimM Thank you! It's soothing to know I could drink the groundwater on a cemetery if I had to. You never know, if and when knowledge comes in handy ;)

Comment: Back in the old days literally every kid knew *ccm*  from playing *Autoquartett* card games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nowadays, most physical units are [internationally standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), and so are their abbreviations. This is the reason why also in Germany the **c**ubic **c**enti**m**etre is abbreviated as **ccm** or **cm<sup>3</sup>**, and not, as one may erroneously deduce from the German word **K**ubik**z**enti**m**eter, as **kzm**. You will find ccm more often than cm<sup>3</sup> in texts written using a typewriter.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kubikzentimer%2CCubikzentimeter%2CCubikcentimeter%2CKubikcentimeter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKubikzentimer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CCubikcentimeter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKubikcentimeter%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ... or km/S instead of km/h.

Comment: "ccm" for "cubic centimeter" seems to be obsolete. I think only "cm³" is standard nowadays.

Comment: The international standard form for *ccm* is probably *ml* (milliliter). 1 ml = 1 ccm.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, see https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubikmeter#Kubikzentimeter_(Milliliter).